# MS Extensions To STL

Tags: c++, stl, visual-studio-2003

If this is a "Google Is Your Friend" question, I apologize in advance.  I've searched but perhaps I've been using the wrong terms for searching.

Can anyone point me to any sort of introductory document on the STL extensions which MS provided with Visual Studio 2003?  I believe the libraries were licensed from Dinkumware and I've seen their docs but they're not helping with this issue.

I'm trying to insure that we've not made some dumb and obvious mistake with our use of these extension containers.  I've not worked on this issue myself--I'm helping another developer--but I believe the issue is something to do with the algorithm to create buckets getting into some sort of infinite loop within the hash_set container.  As I say I just want to make sure we've eliminated obvious and dumb mistakes.

Comment: Get the other developer to ask the question - this is too vague

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, yes, I realize the question is vague.  I wanted to try to get pointers to basic background information so I could try to get a more specific question to ask.  He actually sent me additional details on the exact issue which I'll probably edit into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing Microsoft has done starting with VS 2003 it to put non-standard C++ extensions in the `stdext` namespace:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek139e86(VS.71).aspx

So doing a search on `stdext` (either on the headers or on MSDN) will help you. Note that while the above link talks only about `<hash_set>` and `<hash_map>` (even in the VS 2008 version of the page), the stdext namespace is used for other things such as the checked iterators and checked algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

As usual, Microsoft's API's are documented by Microsoft, on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t4xas78(VS.80).aspx